# Upgrade to PHP7.2 causes memory issues

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My hosting provided upgraded to PHP7.2 and now I started to receive a lot of issues. As my Wordpress theme builder does no longer exist I went through the issues myself fixing problems. For some reason this does not go away and I'm worried about it.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1048576000 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 20480 bytes) in
>   /customers/3/8/4/XXX/httpd.www/wp-content/themes/dejavu/lib/classes/widget-popular.php
>   on line 14

Whenever I increase the limit in wp-config it just keeps growing. Is the problem in that php file or should I look somewhere else? Content of that php file:

```
<?php

/**
 *
 */

class MySite_PopularPost_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     *
     */
    function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'mysite_popular_widget', 'description' => __( 'Custom popular post widget with post preview image', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ) );
        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 250, 'height' => 200 );
        $this->__construct( 'popularwidget', sprintf( __( '%1$s - Popular Post', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ), THEME_NAME ), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    function widget($args, $instance) {
        global $wpdb, $mysite;
        $prefix = MYSITE_PREFIX;

        extract( $args );

        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', empty($instance['title']) ? __('Popular Posts') : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base);

        if ( !$number = (int) $instance['number'] )
            $number = 3;
        else if ( $number < 1 )
            $number = 1;
        else if ( $number > 15 )
            $number = 15;

        echo $before_widget;
        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

        $count = ( !empty( $count ) ) ? trim( $count ) : '3';
        $disable_thumb = $instance['disable_thumb'] ? '1' : '0';

        $popular_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'showposts' => $number,
            'nopaging' => 0,
            'orderby'=> 'comment_count',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'category__not_in' => array( mysite_exclude_category_string( $minus = false )),
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
        ));

        $out = '<ul class="post_list small_post_list">';

        while ( $popular_query->have_posts() ) {
            $popular_query->the_post();

            $out .= '<li class="post_list_module">';

            if( !$disable_thumb ) {
                $widget_thumb_img = $mysite->layout['big_sidebar_images']['small_post_list'];
                $out .= mysite_get_post_image(array(
                    'width' => $widget_thumb_img[0],
                    'height' => $widget_thumb_img[1],
                    'img_class' => 'post_list_image',
                    'preload' => false,
                    'placeholder' => true,
                    'echo' => false,
                    'wp_resize' => ( mysite_get_setting( 'image_resize_type' ) == 'wordpress' ? true : false )
                ));
            }

            $out .= '<div class="post_list_content">';

            $out .= '<p class="post_title">';
            $out .= '<a rel="bookmark" href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( get_the_title() ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
            $out .= '</p>';

            $get_year = get_the_time( 'Y', get_the_ID() );
            $get_month = get_the_time( 'm', get_the_ID() );

            $out .= '<p class="post_meta">';
            $out .= apply_filters( 'mysite_widget_meta', do_shortcode( '[post_date]' ) );
            $out .= '</p>';

            $out .= '</div>';

            $out .= '</li>';
        }

        $out .= '</ul>';

        echo $out;
        echo $after_widget;

        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['number'] = (int) $new_instance['number'];
        $instance['disable_thumb'] = !empty($new_instance['disable_thumb']) ? 1 : 0;

        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    function form($instance) {
        $title = isset($instance['title']) ? esc_attr($instance['title']) : '';
        $disable_thumb = isset( $instance['disable_thumb'] ) ? (bool) $instance['disable_thumb'] : false;
        if ( !isset($instance['number']) || !$number = (int) $instance['number'] )
            $number = 3;
        ?>

        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /></p>

        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('number'); ?>"><?php _e( "Enter the number of popular posts you'd like to display:", MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('number'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('number'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" /></p>

        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('disable_thumb'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('disable_thumb'); ?>"<?php checked( $disable_thumb ); ?> />
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('disable_thumb'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Disable Post Thumbnail?', MYSITE_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN ); ?></label></p>

        <?php
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Appears to be stuck in an infinite loop creating many duplicates of this widget. This is usually easy enough to solve by a programmer but extraordinarily difficult for someone who is not. Do you understand programming? If not you may need to hire someone. It would be easiest if you know how to use a debugger. Otherwise, PHP's debug_backtrace() is the best weapon to get started. But, you absolutely must understand how to read code or be extraordinarily lucky. Good luck.

Comment: 'I went through the issues myself fixing problems.' - Is it a possibility that you created the problem with one of your fixes. I.e., did this problem originally exists or did it appear after you tried to fix the problems. If it is the latter restore back to the original state from backup and carefully do your fixes and observing which one causes the problem.

Comment: Hi, I have some programming background but in other languages, PHP not so much to be honest. I did find the issue though. After some long search..caused an issue during my "fixing". Thanks for the support :)